# Call javascript and c# method with one click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

I have a method in javascript and a method in c#, now with a click on a button I would like to call them both.

First I would like to call the c# method named as `'Find_Direction'` since it gets to inputs onclick and then I will call after the javascript method named as `calcRoute`.

I was trying this, but without any luck:

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" UseSubmitBehavior="False" value="GetDirections" onclick="calcRoute" OnClientClick="Find_Direction" runat="server"/>
```

The following error popped up :

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.findroute_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'calcRoute' and no extension method 'calcRoute' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.findroute_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are specifying javascript function name in onClick event. So put here C# function name

C# code:

```
 protected void  Find_Direction (object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   // do your work

   // Register your javascript function

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", "  <script>calcRoute();</script>");
 }
```

your markup :

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" value="GetDirections" onclick="Find_Direction" runat="server"/>
```

Case 2 : Call javascript function before server side function

Javascript function

```
 function calcRoute() {

        alert('test')
        return true;
    }
```

your markup

```
 <asp:Button id="Button1" value="GetDirections" onclick="Find_Direction " OnClientClick="return Find_Direction()" runat="server"/>
```

By this you can call javascript function then server side but make sure you are returning true from javascript function for calling your server side function.

I Hope, now you can solve your problem. :)

Comment: This way will the find_direction method be executed first? @Sachin

Comment: No. I thought that you want find_Direction to be executed after calcRoute. But no problem if you want find_Direction to be execute first than just call it on client click like `OnClientClick="return Find_Direction"`.

Comment: I am still struggling with it. Since it seems that it is not going in the javscript method.  @Sachin

Comment: Onclick it is going in the Find_Direction method, but than it is not going through the javascript one

Comment: @IT_info I have edited my answer, using case 2, you can call `Find_Direction` first and then `calcRoute` after that. I removed `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` from the markup.have a look.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. But, I want to call first the codebehind which is the Find_Direction() method and after that I want to call the javscript function which is the calcRoute().

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But I am stuck on how to do it. @Sachin

Comment: @IT_info I again updated for you my first case. Now Your problem will solved. and from next time plz make your question very clear. Now mark it as answer plz

Comment: Thanks. I will take the advice

Answer (score 2):

You need an event handler in your code-behind (the aspx.cs or aspx.vb file) called `calcRoute`.

If you want the JS to execute first, you should be able to do it the way you're doing it, with OnClientClick which points to a JS function and OnClick which points to a C#/VB method (event handler).

If you want to be sure that JS gets called after your C# code, you should handle the click on the backend, and then send the JS back to the browser by registering a startup script. This will cause a full post-back, unless you're using an update panel.  In your event handler, you can register a startup script with `Page.RegisterStartupScript` to send a javascript command back to the browser.  In this case, you won't want to use OnClientClick at all.

Comment: But which will be processed first? the calcRoute or the Find_Direction method. I want to be processed first the Find_Direction. @Adam Plocher

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking you wanted it the other way.  OnClientClick should be executed before the post-back/event handler.